# Can't retrieve window.location.href

Tags: javascript, location-href

I have the following code, trying to retrieve the url of the newly open window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
this.windowRef = window.open("http://www.google.com");
console.log(this.windowRef.location.href);
</script>
```

However, when I look at the console of browser, the result shown is: "about:blank", instead of "www.google.com"

Why is that? How do I get www.google.com displayed?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents you from reading data from other domains.